# The door data is not saved in Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

I wrote a door save system.
That is, if the user previously bought them, then when re-entering the game, they must be open.
My code works, but the door doesn't save at all.

```
-- DoorsDataStore
-- Save Stats Doors
local opend = false
local datastorage = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local isitopen_1 = datastorage:GetDataStore("Door")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local boolValueDoors = Instance.new("Folder")
    boolValueDoors.Name = "BoolValueDoors"
    boolValueDoors.Parent = player
    
    local door_1 = Instance.new("BoolValue")
    door_1.Parent = boolValueDoors
    door_1.Name = "BoolValueDoor_1"
    door_1.Value = isitopen_1:GetAsync(player.UserId)  
    print("True or False")
    print(player.BoolValueDoor_1.Value)
end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    
    local success, erromsg = pcall(function()
        isitopen_1:SetAsync(player.UserId, player.BoolValueDoor_1.Value)
    end)
    
    if erromsg then
        warn("Error")
    end
end)
```

```
-- TouchDoor
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local humanoid = hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if (humanoid ~= nil) then
        local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
        if player.leaderstats.Coins.Value >= script.Parent.Price.Value then
            player.leaderstats.Coins.Value -= script.Parent.Price.Value
            player.leaderstats.Level.Value += 1
            script.Parent:Destroy()
            player.BoolValueDoors.BoolValueDoor_1.Value = true
            print("Save Door")
        end
    end
end)
```

I tried writing this code in different ways, in different versions, tried through validation. My code still doesn't do what I want.

Comment: Is the touch door script a local script? Also I noticed that there's no code that detects whether or not the BoolValueDoor_1 is true when a player joins

Comment: It is not localscript. How to check ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple possible problems I see:

1.
SetAsync takes a string as the first argument, you are giving it a number value. To fix this use tostring(player.UserId)

2.
When the player first joins, the value will be set to nil, because there is no data in the datastore under the UserId, and nil is not a boolean.

I’m not sure if these are actual issues and I currently cannot check if these are real problems because I’m not on my computer but they may be something you want to change.
Also it would be nice to know if you encountered any errors when executing the code.

You should also make trigger a remote event that opens the door on the clientside in the PlayerAdded function if the value is true.

Comment: I tried to solve the problem with your methods but it didn't work. So please help me in this. I wrote the code and I didn't get any errors.

Comment: The first script (DoorsDataStore) was written to save player data. This script was supposed to store information about whether the player opened that door or not. If they are open, they must remain open and be stored.

Comment: The second script (TouchDoor) made it so that when the player touched the door, the script checked if the player had the required amount of coins. If there is, 1 level is added and coins are subtracted, and then the leaderboard data is changed. After that, the door disappears, is destroyed (script.Parent:Destroy( )).

Comment: Don’t destroy the door, instead turn its transparency to 1 and set CanCollide to false. Also with the way you scripted it, the door would open for everyone if any player touches it. For it to just be local, use an if statement to ensure that the player that touches the door is the localplayer. For the door to open when rejoining, you have to tell the client to open the door on the client’s side using a remote event. Otherwise, it will save the status of the door but it will not open it if the door was open. Then on a localscript make it so when the event is fired, the door opens.

Comment: The reason you have to use a remote event is because it is a server script, and if you would open the door on a server script, it would open for everyone.

Comment: Also the reason it doesn’t work may be because by destroying the door, you’re destroying the script, which then makes anything written after the destroy statement invalid and will not be run.

Comment: Actually I don’t know if you want the door to only be opened on the clientside. If you don’t want it just to be opened on the clientside and instead on the serverside, just open the door in the script instead of using remoteevents.

Comment: I don't really understand you. I want to store information about each player's door opening. I've never used remote events before, so I don't know much about them.

Comment: You can find information on remote events and how to use them in the roblox creator documentation.